# Optimization and Deep Learning: Is ReLU a Closed Function

Tags: analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The ReLU activation function in deep learning is given by $\text{ReLU}: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R, x \mapsto \max\left\{0, x\right\}$. I was asking myself whether this function, which is convex, is also closed. This is the general definition of **closed**:

**Definition.** A function $J: X\rightarrow \mathbb R_{\infty} := \mathbb R \ \cup \left\{ \pm \infty \right\}$ is **closed** if its epigraph is closed.

**Definition**. The epigraph of $J$ is given by $\text{epi}(J) := \left\{ (x, \alpha)\in X\times \mathbb R \ \vert \ J(x) \leq \alpha \right\}$.

I sketched myself the $ReLU$ functions and its epigraphs, and using that every function is closed if and only if contains all its limit points, it *looks* like $\text{epi}(\text{ReLU})$ is closed. But I am not sure what a mathematically rigorous proof would look like..

Answer (score 1):

The function is closed if and only if the epigraph is closed. But the ReLu function is continuous, which implies closedness of epigraph.

The epi graph is the set:
$$
\{ (x,\alpha) :  \max(0,x) \le \alpha\},
$$
which is the preimage of the closed set $[0,+\infty)$ under the continuous map $x\mapsto \max(x,0)-\alpha$.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I can give you a rigorous proof, but I don't think you need one. I think you got to the same conclusion that the epigraph of the ReLU function is $\{ (x, y) \colon x \geq 0, y \leq x\}$, which is closed.

Comment: This is *not* the epi-graph.